# Setting Default and Options in Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I implemented the jquery plugin with default and options. Here is the working sample **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vicky081/WTNLq/15/)** Everything seems ok but one question is when i call the function with following arguments is applicable for body tag. But i don't want this body tag appending to execute the function of jquery.
For example.

```
$(function(){  
    $("body").gettingmessage({variable1:false})  
});
```

That function is appending with body inorder to execute. This is the only way of doing?

```
$(function(){  
    $.fn.gettingmessage({variable1:true})  
});
```

This also working. But I am not sure this is the correct way of calling the function without any `tag or id or class`

Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't need an element, then don't make it a jQuery plugin. Make it a standalone function.

Comment: Thanks for your info. Is that feasibility of doing without element that my question?